# Regular Expression unique result

Tags: regex, http-headers, substring

I have a regular expression

```
(?:(da|en-gb|en|\*))(?!.*\1)
```

What I want to get is to match unique language-type;

For example, I give `enenen-gben` the match part is `en-gben`,this is what I want because the former two `en` are repeated.

However when I give `enenenen-gb` the match part is `en-gb`, What I what to get is `enen-gb`, I think the reason is that `en` is a substring of `en-gb`. But I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone give me a better RE? Many Thanks

===================update==============

The background of the question is that I want to design a Regex for the http header of accept-language. So I use `(?:(da|en-gb|en|\*))(?!.*\1)(;q=(1|0(\.\d+)?))?(,(da|en-gb|en|\*)(;q=(1|0(\.\d+)?))?)*` here `da`,`en-gb`,`en` are just some samples. You know, every language can be assigned a value q to represent its priority. And I do not hope any repeated language type occur. This is what I want.

Comment: @anubhava I don't think this question related to the language you use. I am just design a regex for representing the different language type. Actually, the case is that I have set of language types and I want to represent them using regex without repeated ones.

Comment: Try [`(?:(da|en-gb|en|\*))(?!.*\1(?!-))`](https://regex101.com/r/mN6qR7/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't work. Have you tried this?

Comment: It does, why do you ask - I provided a demo link. Here is another: https://regex101.com/r/mN6qR7/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I didn't notice it was a link. Yes, it works. But another problem is that when I try `en;q=0,da;q=0.4,*;q=0.4,da;q=0.4`, it cannot work, the two `da` will be matched. I guess that is because it will only filter the first language type, what do you think? Many Thanks

Comment: So, try [`(?:(da|en-gb|en|\*))(?!.*\1(?!-))(?:;q=(?:1|0(\.\d+)?))?(?:,(da|en-gb|en|\*)(?!.*\3)(?:;q=(?:1|0(?:\.\d+)?))?)*`](https://regex101.com/r/mN6qR7/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. This works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `(?!-)` negative lookahead after the backreferences to restrict the matches to not have a hyphen right after the duplicated language name:

```
(?:(da|en-gb|en|\*))(?!.*\1(?!-))(?:;q=(?:1|0(\.\d+)?))?(?:,(da|en-gb|en|\*)(?!.*\3(?!-))(?:;q=(?:1|0(?:\.\d+)?))?)*
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN6qR7/5)

If there is a `-`, this substring will not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

One fix that I can think of is changing the `en` to `en-us` as other language type is `en-gb` which is British English, previous one should be American English.

If you are okay with it then this might work as follows.

**Regex:** `(en-gb|en-us|da)(?!\1)(en-gb|en-us|da)`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iW0oA3/2)**

Comment: Thanks, but is there any solution if I don't change the `en` to `en-us`. Another thing I want to ask is that I noticed that you use `(?!\1)` while I use `(?!.*\1)` for not repeating. Would please tell me the difference between them? Many Thanks

Comment: When you use `.*` it means  there could be `zero` or `many` characters between matched and repeated string. I hope you want to match successively repeated string. In that case matched string and following string should be consecutive without any character between them.

Comment: If you don't change `en` to `en-us` then matched `en` will consider substring of `en-gb` as it's repetition and will consider it as repeated `en`.

Comment: *Is there any solution if I don't change the `en` to `en-us`.* - What **can** you change in the pattern? Please add those details to the question body.

Comment: @noob Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the question, thanks. If you need more information for solving the problem, please tell me. Thank you very much